# Easy way to darken the background color little by little

Tags: css, background, gradient, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to create a responsive fullpage website, I have 7 sections  and one of my goals is create a background color that starts from `white` then whenever the user scrolls down the way to section 7 I want it become dark. Actually I can do this but it takes a lot of my time due to getting the correct amount of darkness, it is also worth mentioning that I am using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) to create a gradient background.

In short I want to do the following:

1. I want to intensify the color starting from white to dark.
2. If possible can you make it adjustable? Let's I also want a background that start from white down to dark red, from blue to white, etc.

So far I am using this code to put background in every section of my website, as you can see it is very hard to maintain, and the code seems to huge. Can I do something like A = White then B = Gray then that function will automatically gradient it from white down to gray?

/* Section 1
* --------------------------------------- */

## section1{

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 37%, rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 65%, rgba(187,187,187,0.05) 96%, rgba(178,178,178,0.05) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(37%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(65%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55)), color-stop(96%,rgba(187,187,187,0.05)), color-stop(100%,rgba(178,178,178,0.05)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 37%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 65%,rgba(187,187,187,0.05) 96%,rgba(178,178,178,0.05) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 37%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 65%,rgba(187,187,187,0.05) 96%,rgba(178,178,178,0.05) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 37%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 65%,rgba(187,187,187,0.05) 96%,rgba(178,178,178,0.05) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 37%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 65%,rgba(187,187,187,0.05) 96%,rgba(178,178,178,0.05) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#0db2b2b2',GradientType=0 );
```

}
/* Section 2 
* --------------------------------------- */

## section2{

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,206,206,0.15) 0%, rgba(207,207,207,0.15) 10%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 96%, rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(206,206,206,0.15)), color-stop(10%,rgba(207,207,207,0.15)), color-stop(96%,rgba(216,216,216,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(216,216,216,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,206,206,0.15) 0%,rgba(207,207,207,0.15) 10%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 96%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,206,206,0.15) 0%,rgba(207,207,207,0.15) 10%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 96%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(206,206,206,0.15) 0%,rgba(207,207,207,0.15) 10%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 96%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(206,206,206,0.15) 0%,rgba(207,207,207,0.15) 10%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 96%,rgba(216,216,216,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#26cecece', endColorstr='#d8d8d8',GradientType=0 );
```

}
/* Section 3 
* --------------------------------------- */

## section3{

```
background: rgb(226,226,226);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(201,201,201,1) 69%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(226,226,226,1)), color-stop(69%,rgba(201,201,201,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(201,201,201,1) 69%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(201,201,201,1) 69%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(201,201,201,1) 69%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(201,201,201,1) 69%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#c9c9c9',GradientType=0 );
```

}

/* Section 4
* --------------------------------------- */

## section4{

```
background: rgb(186,186,186);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%, rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(186,186,186,1)), color-stop(32%,rgba(147,147,147,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bababa', endColorstr='#939393',GradientType=0 );
```

}
/* Section 5
* --------------------------------------- */

## section5{

```
background: rgb(186,186,186);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%, rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(186,186,186,1)), color-stop(32%,rgba(147,147,147,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bababa', endColorstr='#939393',GradientType=0 );
```

}

/* Section 6
* --------------------------------------- */

## section6{

```
background: rgb(186,186,186);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%, rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(186,186,186,1)), color-stop(32%,rgba(147,147,147,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bababa', endColorstr='#939393',GradientType=0 );
```

}

/* Section 7
* --------------------------------------- */

## section7{

```
background: rgb(186,186,186);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%, rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(186,186,186,1)), color-stop(32%,rgba(147,147,147,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(186,186,186,1) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 32%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bababa', endColorstr='#939393',GradientType=0 );
```

}

Comment: what's the problem exactly? In which way css3 gradients don't work for you? what have you tried? why it takes you a lot of time?

Comment: If you just want to reduce the amount of code, you could work with SASS or LESS and create a mixin (there are also already some good [mixin libraries](http://lesselements.com/) out there, that do exactly that) that takes 2 parameters and creates the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably looked on that if I have some time.